# Turn list elements in dataframe into columns pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have this little issue. I have a Dataframe with the following shape:

```
id    d
1   [1,2,3]
2   [4,5,6]
```

And I want to turn it into this:

```
id    d      v1  v2  v3
1   [1,2,3]   1   2   3
2   [4,5,6]   4   5   6
```

I tried this:

```
for i in A['d']:
A['v1']=i[0]
A['v2']=i[1]
A['v3']=i[2]
```

But this gets me the following:

```
id    d      v1  v2  v3
1   [1,2,3]   4   5   6
2   [4,5,6]   4   5   6
```

(It's pasting the elements of the last list in every row). I'm sure my error is little but I can't find it. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(df.d.values.tolist())], 1 )`

Comment: This gives a weird Dataframe with lots of NaN values. I'm not sure what's happening, though

Comment: What is in d?  is it a string or a list?

Comment: Edit: I had issues with the index. After resetting it everything worked, thanks !